# FailedPreconditionError when running my code in Anaconda Spyder

Tags: python

When I run my code, it shows below error:

> FailedPreconditionError: Failed to rename: ./output_2019-01- 23_20_04_53/weights/weights_epoch_1000.ckpt.index.tempstate4247192991249699806 to: ./output_2019-01-23_20_04_53/weights/weights_epoch_1000.ckpt.index : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
>       ; Broken pipe

Anyone can help me how to fixed this error?

I'm using Anaconda Spyder to run the code.

Comment: It's hard to know what is wrong without seeing the code related to the file you are trying to rename.  I suspect you have opened the file and not closed it before you try to rename it.  Are you specifically opening and closing the file or are you using context managers?

Comment: Thank you for your response Rachel, i didn't have any file open, i just run my code from Anaconda Spyder. Here the link of partially code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qovlxf7o203Zml_CRNUYs44St7xCzXbl/view?usp=sharing, and the error message: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZzJ2KTDLXzafjPT1EmzrFHGy6IShBNjj/view?usp=sharing. Thank you so much for your help.